# How to remove only one translation in CakePHP's TranslateBehavior?

Tags: php, cakephp, behavior, translate

I have a model with TranslateBehavior attached to it and I wonder if there is a method to remove only one translation of specific item and use only standard model methods (=not provide SQL query on i18n table explicitly, because I want to be absolutely independent of DB engine) and not set it blank but really remove.

Simple situation example:
There is an article in DB with translations in English and German. One day editor decides not to provide this article in German and wants to remove it from DB (but English version should be still available). And now appears the question I wrote above.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for now after examining *afterSave* callback in the behavior class I see only some kind of workaround - to use the core model **I18nModel** defined in *cake/libs/model/behavior/translate.php* (bottom of the file) and use *delete* method with manually set all conditions that normally are set by translateBehavior.

The **I18nModel** model can be used in standard way:

```
    var $uses = array('SomeModelUsingTranlateBehaviour','I18nModel');
```